Can the Sledgehammer reflect a Frisbee?
The Sledgehammer weapon is able to reflect enemy projectiles. The Frisbee weapon can kill you if it bounces off a wall and hits you. Thrown Frisbees can be reflected with the Frisbee's alternate fire.
If you throw a Frisbee then pick up a Sledgehammer, can the Sledgehammer reflect the thrown Frisbee?
